# DROP and CREATE View in PHP - single query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to DROP and CREATE a view in mySQL using this code in PHP:

```
$hours_sum_build = "DROP VIEW hours_sum;";
$hours_sum_build .= "CREATE VIEW hours_sum as
  SELECT emp_id, first_name, last_name, pp_end, date, sum(hours) as 
  hours, time_source, run_date, run_time
  FROM merged_time_report GROUP BY emp_id";

mysqli_multi_query($conn, $hours_sum_build);

echo "Debug: $hours_sum_build";
$result = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $hours_sum_build);
if ( false===$result ) {
  printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
}
 else {
 echo 'done.';
}
```

I obviously want to DROP the view then immediately create it again.  But when I run the above code, I get this error message:

```
Debug: DROP VIEW hours_sum;CREATE VIEW hours_sum as
SELECT emp_id, first_name, last_name, pp_end, date, sum(hours) as 
hours, time_source, run_date, run_time
FROM merged_time_report GROUP BY emp_id

error: 

Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
null results for hours_sum_count
null results for first_pass_count
null results for pass_fail_count
Error: 
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
Error: 
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
Error: 
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
null
```

When the view is created (I can do that through phpMyAdmin), it returns results in the three variables identified above (hours_sum_count, etc.), so it makes sense that these are null in my scenario because the view is not being created in PHP using mysqli_multi_query.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW...` Also why are you dropping and creating the same view multiple times?

Comment: We run data multiple times over the course of our pay period.  I will try REPLACE VIEW, thank you!

Comment: That is the point of a view. It calculates the results at runtime. It basically saves the sql and runs it when you need it. You only need to create it once and it doesn't/shouldn't be done in your PHP. Create the view, with phpmyadmin, then query the view in your PHP code. Something like `select * from hours_sum`

Comment: Got it thanks - I was thinking of Views as temporary tables, and less like stored queries.  This simplifies things - thank you!